# How to design the ShellView with Caliburn Micro?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

Let's say I want to create an Application similar to the Windows Explorer. I'd need some modules (assemblies) like these

```
- MyApp.Modules.NavPane
- MyApp.Modules.Ribbon
- MyApp.Modules.StatusBar
- MyApp.Modules.Body
```

Then I have another 2 modules for my entry point and a shell

```
- MyApp.Core
- MyApp.Shell
```

So now my issue is: **what is the correct way to lay out my app?** Do I design everything in my ShellView and just hard-reference my modules?

By hard-reference I mean I set an actual reference to my module assembly, constructor inject the ViewModels I need (`NavPaneViewModel`, `RibbonViewModel`, ...) and put them in my ShellView with `ContentControl`s

Here some pseudo-ish code

```
public class ShellViewModel 
{
    public Screen NavPane { get; }

    public ShellViewModel(NavPaneViewModel navPane, ...) 
    {
        NavPane = navPane;
        // ...
    }
}
```

and my ShellView

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.ShellView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions><!--...--></Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions><!--...--></Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ContentControl x:Name="NavPane" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: That's basically how I've done my application and it works well.

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: You should go with `PRISM` if modularity is all you want. There are various approached to load modules dynamically.